# Input validation: Validation message and ng-disabled buttons not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-validation

I have the following code which I'm trying to validate using AngularJS:

```
<div ng-form="transWizard" novalidate>
    <div style="word-wrap:break-word; padding-top:4px; padding-left:14px">
        <p style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular'; font-size:17.5px;"><span style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Semibold'">Question {{carousel.currentQuestionIndex+1}}:</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.question}}</p>

        <ul style="padding-left:30px;">
            <li ng-repeat="query in carousel.currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                <input class="TWInputField" name="inputname" 
                           type="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" 
                           ng-model="query.selected" ng-change="carousel.changeOnSelection(query.selected, query.id)"
                           value="" ng-value="true" ng-required="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType === 'radio' || carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType === 'text' ? true : false}}">

                <label for="{{query.id}}" style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{query.question}}</label>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <p class="msg-required" ng-show="transWizard.inputname.$invalid">
                Input is required.
        </p>

    </div>

   <div class="carousel-wizard-btn-container">
        <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="carousel.wizardPrevious()" ng-hide="carousel.currentQuestionIndex == 0">Previous</div>
        <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="carousel.wizardNext()" ng-hide="carousel.currentQuestionIndex == carousel.wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="transWizard.$invalid">Next</div>
        <div class="carousel-wizard-buttons" ng-click="carousel.showResults()" ng-show="carousel.currentQuestionIndex == carousel.wizardQuestionSet.length - 1" ng-disabled="transWizard.$invalid">Finish</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm not using the `<form>` tag, but I've read that it's possible to validate even without using forms thanks to the `ng-form` directive.

My conditions are to require input only if type is `radio` or `text`.

However, when I executed this, I got the following:

1. ng-disabled is not working for the Next button. I can still click it even though I haven't selected any answers for the required sections.
2. Validation message only disappears when I click the last item in a set of radio buttoned-questions.

Am I missing something here?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

your validation will not work as expected  because u are using same  name for input controls in **ng-repeat**.

you  can use ng-form inside ng-repeat like this.

```
 <div ng-form="transWizard" novalidate>

<li ng-repeat="query in carousel.currentQuestionObject.choices" style="padding-bottom:5px;">

<ng-form name="innerForm" >
<input class="TWInputField" name="inputname" type="  {{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType}}" id="{{query.id}}" ng-model="query.selected" ng-change="carousel.changeOnSelection(query.selected, query.id)" value="" ng-value="true" ng-required="{{carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType === 'radio' || carousel.currentQuestionObject.inputType === 'text' ? true : false}}">

<label for="{{query.id}}" style="font-family:'MetricWeb-Regular';font-size:17px;cursor:pointer">&nbsp;&nbsp;{{query.question}}</label>

<p class="msg-required" ng-show="innerForm.inputname.$invalid">
    Input is required.
</p>
</ng-form>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your solution. It works, however it places "Input is required" at the end of every choice. The message should be after all the <li> items are iterated. Is there a way to make that happen?